# Appjar AutoEntry not working inside a subWindow

Tags: python, appjar

I am trying to create a GUI to navigate RNAseq data. It asks the user which species, then to select cell types (new subwindow), then genes (new subWindow opened upon button press from cell types window). The gene selector portion works when it stands alone, using autoEntry fields. But when I put it inside a subWindow, the fields do not autopopulate and the drop down of the genes does not appear. Even defining the list that it uses inside the subWindow definition did not help. Any ideas?
Thanks

-Dana

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a quick try, on the latest release, and didn't see any issues, can you try this code:

```
from appJar import gui 

words = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccd', 'cce']

with gui() as app:
    app.entry('words', words, kind='auto')
    app.button('SubWindow Test', app.showSubWindow)

    with app.subWindow('SubWindow Test'):
        app.entry('words2', words, kind='auto')
```